# how to use multiple if(isset($_POST)) inside php variable

Tags: php, forms, variables, checkbox, isset

On a page with multiple checkboxes to select products, I would like to send an email with the selected checkboxes.

The following code successfully outputs what I like after clicking the submit button, but on the webpage. I just cannot figure out how to include the results in the email instead.

Here's the html form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="product1"><input type="checkbox" class="equipment[]" id="product1" name="product1" value="100">Add to inquiry</label>
    <label for="product2"><input type="checkbox" class="equipment[]" id="product2" name="product2" value="50">Add to inquiry</label>
    <label for="product3"><input type="checkbox" class="equipment[]" id="product3" name="product3" value="80">Add to inquiry</label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="formsubmitbtn" value="Send inquiry">
</form>
```

This is the PHP code that successfully prints the results on the page:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['product1'])){
    echo "checked Product Name 1"."<br>";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['product2'])){
        echo "checked Product Name 2"."<br>";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['product3'])){
        echo "checked Product Name 3";
    }
?>
```

The result (which is perfect for me) is:
checked Product Name 1
checked Product Name 2
checked Product Name 3

Now I'd like to put the result inside the email message instead. Here's the PHP for the email:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "myemailaddress";
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address

    $gearselection = ???;

    $subject = "Inquiry";
    $message = $from . "\n\n" . $gearselection;

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "Your inquiry has been sent.";
    }
?>
```

And in **$gearselection** I would like to output the results from the code above.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Then simply append to a string variable, instead of using echo.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you researched? What have you tried? To be clear, we'll help you at stackoverflow but we're not a free do-my-thinking service 
See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it should be the `name` attribute that gets the square bracket, not the class and this `name` attribute should be defined on the `input` checkbox not the `label`.

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" id="product1" value="Product 1">
  <label for="product1">Product 1</label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" id="product2" value="Product 2">
  <label for="product2">Product 2</label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" id="product3" value="Product 3">
  <label for="product3">Product 3</label>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="formsubmitbtn" value="Send inquiry">
</form>
```

And then on the PHP side, you'll get an array of values depending on what's checked off for `$_POST['product']` - you can just loop through them to get all of the items that were selected.

```php
if(!empty($_POST['product'])) {
  foreach($_POST['product'] as $p) {
    echo $p;
  }
}
```

In your email, you could do something like:

```php
if(!empty($_POST['product'])) {
  $gearselection = implode(', ', $_POST['product']);
}
```